# process-resource-bundles maven error calssnotfoundexception org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, osgi, maven-plugin

Trying to build an example from camel via `mvn package`

apache-camel-2.22.0/examples/camel-example-cdi-xml

Getting an error never seen before, i checked dependency tree for transitive deps and apache-collections is 3.2.1 and not corrupt so can't explain it, obviously i know what it means, just can't figure out why it's happening because everything that should be required is provided:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (process-resource-bundles) on project camel-example-cdi-xml: Execution process-resource-bundles of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
```

Not really sure how to trouble shoot it.

I tried building with several different versions of maven. JDK = 1.8

Answer (score 0):

update pom.xml add the following code

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bundle</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```